# Comunicação entre dois programas em PYTHON

Tags: python

Galera, estou desenvolvendo dois programas que têm que se comunicarem entre si, tentei a maneira de importar o outro programa, mas quando executo os dois eles se comportam como um único código, e não é isso que quero. É necessário que fiquem como código distintos.

Quero poder utilizar os valores das variáveis do outro código. Um código se comunica com o Arduíno via serial e recebe valores dele, o outro tira fts com uma câmera e as salva de acordo com cada valor lido da serial.

Comment: Que tipo de comunicação precisa?

Comment: quero poder utilizar os valores das variáveis do outro código. Um código se comunica com o Arduíno via serial e recebe valores dele, o outro tira fts com uma câmera e as salva de acordo com cada valor lido da serial.

Comment: quem quer que tenhamarcado para "fechar" - acredito que agora a pergunta seja respondível, e a resposta pode ser útil para bastante gente.

Comment: Obrigado, estou na espera de alguma ajuda, se precisarem de mais informações, eu darei.

Comment: Para mim só não ficou muito claro a necessidade de fazer isso em dois programas distintos. Você não conseguiria executar o processo de tirar a foto no momento que recebe o dado via serial, através de uma thread, por exemplo? Aliás, talvez seria interessante você adicionar à pergunta esses códigos para notear melhor as respostas.

Comment: Tentei na Thread mas como estou utilizando a Raspberry pi3 ele tipo que sobrecarrega o processamento, vai a 100%. No programa que se comunica com o Arduíno eu também utilizo a pygame para a utilização de um Joystick, quando rodei os códigos separadamente funcionou tranquilo, tipo um só tirando fts e o outro programa utilizando o Joystick e se comunicando com o Arduino, mas sem os programas interagirem um com o outro.

Answer (score 3):

Então - isso pode variar do "fácil" ao "complicado" - principalmente se você for colocar isso em produção e quiser ter alguma segurança de quem chama o que.

Vou tentar listar algumas opções e dar o caminho das pedras para algumas delas:

## Talvez você não precise de mais de um processo:

Tem que ver o quanto você quer "complicar" sua vida - se em um processo você fica num loop `while` lendo valores da serial, e só quer que o código controlador da câmera possa ver esses valores, nada impede que tudo esteja num programa só, e é só uma questão de refatorar o seu código.

Um bom jeito de fazer isso é colocar tanto o seu código que le valores da serial quanto e opcionalmente o da câmera em co-rotinas, usando "yield".

Então, supondo que seu código agora seja algo do tipo:

```
def principal():
    # codigo para configurar a serial
    while True:
        valor = funcao_pra_ler_da_serial()
        # quero que o código da camera receba "valor"
        #
        # Num loop continuo é importante forçar uma pausa
        # pra nao usar mais CPU que o necessário:
        time.sleep(0.05)

principal()
```

Você pode entao re-escrever esse trecho para ser algo assim:

```
def le_valores():
    # codigo para configurar a serial
    while True:
        valor = funcao_pra_ler_da_serial()
        yield valor

def principal():
   gerador_de_valores = le_valores()
   while True:
       time.sleep(0.05)
       valor = next(gerador_de_valores)
       if <expressao_usando "valor">:
            funcao_que_tira_foto()
       time.sleep(0.05)

principal()
```

## Multiprocessing - Base de Código única

Se um programa tiver como importar o outro, ou você puder escrever um programa que possa importar os dois - você pode usar o Python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). Você cria uma função que controla cada uma das operações desejadas, chama cada uma num processo diferente, e usa uma `multiprocessing.Queue` para passar dados entre as duas partes do seu código.

Esse vai ser o método mais simples.

## Celery

celery é a "forma padrão" de chamar funções fora do processo em ambientes de produção hoje em dia. Mesmo por que, ao contrário do Multiprocessing, você pode montar configurações em que os processos estejam em máquinas diferentes, sistemas operacionais diferentes, etc...

O lado negativo é que ele precisa de um sistema intermediário que funcione como um "broker" para passar as mensagens de um processo para outro. Isso é um serviço instalado a parte, tal como redis ou rabbitmq. Para rodar numa máquina local, isso é bem simples, e os valores padrão são o suficiente. Para produção, é cavocar a documentação e construir seu broker a prova de furos, com autenticação, e etc...

Ele também necessita que um processo possa importar o código do outro - embora ele precise disso só para "saber" os nomes das funções, que são chamadas como tarefas do celery. O primeiro exemplo do tutorial acho que é bem claro.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html

## xmlrpc ou jsonrpc

Essa é uma forma que antigamente já foi mais fácil de configurar. Hoje, com os exemplos existentes é possível, mas pode dar algum trabalho a mais - por conta de algumas correções para se evitar falhas de segurança que foram descobertas ao longo do tempo, e também por que o método não evoluiu para utilizar Unicode de forma transparente com o Python3.

Mas basicamente é a forma mais simples que não exige que um dos processos possa importar o código do outro, e ainda permite que cada processo esteja numa versão diferente do Python (Python 2 e Python 3, ou pode-se misturar pypy, Jython, FePython, etc...)

Como mencionei anteriormente, um dos seus processos então terá que ter o papel de "servidor" - ele vai expor métodos que poderão ser chamados a partir de processos de fora:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.server.html#module-xmlrpc.server

## Considerações finais:

Perceba que nenhum desses métodos vai deixar você simplesmente "ler uma variável" de um outro processo em tempo real, como você lê uma variável de um módulo que é importado  - a maior parte deles exige que você chame uma função remotamente, e então você tem o valor de retorno dessa função. Isso quer dizer que você provavelmente vai ter que refatorar seu código de qualquer forma. A exceção é o método com multiprocessing, que pode usar um objeto do tipo `Queue` para compartilhar os dados.

Comment: Obrigado cara, vou testar aqui, show sua resposta.